# Set button background from style

Tags: java, android

This is a part of my styles.xml file. For some reason textColor works but background color does not.

How do I make it work?

```
<style name="myDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/myDialogButton</item>
</style>

<style name="myDialogButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#0000FF</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `backgroundTint` instead of `background` in buttons

```
<style name="myDialogButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#0000FF</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```